# boost error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator==’

Tags: c++, boost

Has anyone seen this error in boost?

I am compiling my project with boost 1.62 with GCC 7.1 on CentOS 7 and I have got compile errors below

Is it a boost bug or something else?

Thanks

```
boost/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/random/detail/polynomial.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::random::detail::polynomial::normalize()’:
boost/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/random/detail/polynomial.hpp:352:45: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘boost::random::detail::polynomial::reference’ and ‘int’)
     while(size() && (*this)[size() - 1] == 0)
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
boost/boost-1.62.0/include/boost/random/detail/polynomial.hpp:352:45: note: candidate: operator==(int, int) <built-in>

xxx.h:393:17: note: candidate: bool operator==(const bool&, const CPolyVal&)
 STR_INLINE bool operator==(const TYPE& val, const CPolyVal& cpv)\
                 ^
xxx.h:400:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO’
 IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(bool)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xxx.h:393:17: note: candidate: bool operator==(const char&, const CPolyVal&)
 STR_INLINE bool operator==(const TYPE& val, const CPolyVal& cpv)\
                 ^
xxx.h:401:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO’
 IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(char)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

a lot more like this.

**Updated error logs.**

In somewhere in our codebase.

```
#define IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(TYPE)\
STR_INLINE bool operator==(const TYPE& val, const CPolyVal& cpv)\
{\
    TYPE cpv_equiv_val;\
    return cpv.ConvertTo(cpv_equiv_val) == val;\
}\
// end macro

IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(bool)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(char)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(Int8)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(Int16)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(Int32)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(Int64)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(UInt8)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(UInt16)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(UInt32)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(UInt64)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(Float32)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(Float64)
IMPLEMENT_RHS_COMPARE_TO(std::string)
```

Comment: Maybe it should be `while((0 != size()) && (0 == (*this)[size() - 1]))`

Comment: What is the other candidate? You only quoted one. Did the compiler tell you what the other candidate is?

Comment: @VTT Apart from being less readable, it is absolutely equivalent...

Comment: GCC at Coliru seems to have no problems with it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/180110be2a8cd7da. Their Boost code inside `normalize` is the same: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24065740987685e8

Comment: @AnT Other candidate are coming from our own codes not from boost, so I didn't post them.

Comment: @danielkim Well, how are we supposed to tell you what the problem with *your code* is if you do not show us *your code* or the error messages referring to *your code*?

Comment: When I look at code in polynomial.hpp, (*this)[size() - 1] returns 'polynomial::reference' and comparing with 'int' like compile says. It looks obvious error. However visaul studio and gcc 4.7 do not complain about it .

Comment: @daniel kim: `boost::random::detail::polynomial::reference` is implicitly convertible to `bool` (it defines `operator bool() const`). This is exactly how this comparison should work: the LHS should get implicitly converted to `bool`, and `0` on the RHS should be interpreted as `false`. The built-in `bool` vs. `bool` comparison should take place here. Or, more precisely, `int` vs. `int` comparison after usual arithmetic conversions. That's why the compiler lists it as the first candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by what you posted in the comments, you somehow managed to declare some intrusive and overly broad overloaded `==` operator (a template?) that competes with the comparison function intended by Boost authors. In this case Boosts intends the `boost::random::detail::polynomial::reference` on the left-hand side to get implicitly converted to `bool` by a user defined conversion operator, while `0` at the right-hand side should be interpreted as `false`. So, the intent is to use the built in `int` vs. `int` comparison to compare two `bool` values.

Your operator `==` declarations are apparently visible to Boost code at that point and produce the ambiguity. E.g. something like that happens

```
// Very loose and broad template comparison operator gets declared above
// It can compare anything to `bool`
template <typename T> bool operator ==(T lhs, bool rhs)
{
  return false;
}

// Unsuspecting code begins here
// It assumes that `S` vs. `int` comparisons will be interpreted as
// built-in `bool` vs. `bool` comparisons
struct S
{
    operator bool() const { return false; }

    void normalize()
    {
        S s;
        s == 0; // Error: ambiguous comparison
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes you're right.  I updated error logs as well. So what is the possible way to fix?  Removing that header file from 'include' chains?  but it is quite hard to do this because of very deep nested include chains in our huge code base.

Comment: @daniel kim: Can you at first try to ensure that *your* headers are always included *after* Boost headers and never *before* Boost headers. This might solve it. Admittedly, this is a rather fragile approach, but it might work in your case.

Comment: Also, what is `CPolyVal`?

Comment: It is our own class to hold different type's value.

Comment: @daniel kim: It appears to be *implicitly* convertible from `0`. Is this implict conversion really necessary for you? If you restrict it to *explicit* conversions only, the problem will go away.

Comment: Fixed it by chaning headers so boost headers are included first. Thanks a lot. @AnT